# Nested JSON Array C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am trying to deserialize a JSON array that has an additional nested object.
Here is a sample C# code. It returns data until it gets to the second array. I know it needs a second `foreach` loop but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
            string sJSON = @"   [{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":0,""customerNumber"":12,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":333,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department A""},{""department"":111,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department B""}]},{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":3,""customerNumber"":3,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":999,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department X""},{""department"":888,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department Y""}]}]";

            JArray a = JArray.Parse(sJSON);

            foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
            {
                foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
                {
                    string name = p.Name;
                    string value = (string)p.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(name + "-- " + value);
                }
            }
```

Comment: make sure your json is in valid format

Comment: This is the format I have to work with. I believe that it is valid. It works when I paste it into JSON editor online.

Comment: Here is the JSON without the double quotes for the C#
 string.[{"dateNumeric":1216000000,"hourOfDay":0,"customerNumber":12,"storedepartment":[{"department":333,"descriptionOfDepartment":"Department A"},{"department":111,"descriptionOfDepartment":"Department B"}]},{"dateNumeric":1216000000,"hourOfDay":3,"customerNumber":3,"storedepartment":[{"department":999,"descriptionOfDepartment":"Department X"},{"department":888,"descriptionOfDepartment":"Department Y"}]}]

Comment: Json is perfectly fine.

Comment: have you tried using past special in visual studio? it will automatically generate the class for you based on the your JSON. after doing that you can easily use newtonsoft to deserialize your JSON string

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.json library for serializing/deserializing the data, as per your requirement kindly follow below code :

First you need to create the class which will capture the data in specified format(as per your data requirement) :

```
 public class RootObject
  {
        public int dateNumeric { get; set; }
        public int hourOfDay { get; set; }
        public int customerNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Storedepartment> storedepartment { get; set; }
  }

  public class Storedepartment
  {
        public int department { get; set; }
        public string descriptionOfDepartment { get; set; }
  }
```

Now , for deserialising the Json data use below statement :

```
 string sJSON = @"   [{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":0,""customerNumber"":12,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":333,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department A""},{""department"":111,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department B""}]},{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":3,""customerNumber"":3,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":999,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department X""},{""department"":888,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department Y""}]}]";

 List<RootObject> Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(sJSON);
```

Once you get data in your list you can perform your required operation on list

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work with either of these solutions. I will try it in the AM.

Comment: One more question? I can loop through the parent records but how to I access the child data for Storeddepartment?                                                            List<RootObject> Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(sJSON);

                foreach (RootObject c in Data)
                { 
                    debugOutput(c.dateNumeric.ToString());
                    debugOutput(c.customerNumber.ToString());
                }

Comment: foreach(RootObject objData in Data)
           {
               if(objData.storedepartment!=null)
               {
                   foreach(Storedepartment objStorDept in objData.storedepartment)
                   {
                       //you can access Storeddepartment obj here
                   }
               }
           }

Answer (score 0):

Actually you might be able to properly parse your JSON string if you use the following approach.

```
    public static void ProcessJObject(JProperty obj)
    {
        string name = obj.Name;
        string value = "";
        if (obj.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Array: " + name);
            ProcessJArray((JArray)obj.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            value = (string)obj.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(name + "-- " + value);
        }


    }


    public static void ProcessJArray(JArray arr)
    {
        foreach (JObject o in arr.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
            {
                ProcessJObject(p);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sJSON = @"   [{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":0,""customerNumber"":12,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":333,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department A""},{""department"":111,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department B""}]},{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":3,""customerNumber"":3,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":999,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department X""},{""department"":888,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department Y""}]}]";


        JArray a = JArray.Parse(sJSON);

        ProcessJArray(a);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

So what have I done here. I simply divided the problem of parsing json in two smaller problems one that is solved by the ProcessJObject function (parsing and printing JProperty) and one that is solved by the ProcessJArray function (looping through the JArray and for each JProperty it contain passing it to ProcessJObject function). So now the parsing problem upto any point of nesting of JSON array is solved by the above approach.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work with either of these solutions. I will try it in the AM.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void JsonConvert()
{
    string sJSON = @"[{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":0,""customerNumber"":12,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":333,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department A""},{""department"":111,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department B""}]},{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":3,""customerNumber"":3,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":999,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department X""},{""department"":888,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department Y""}]}]";

    var storeDetail = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StoreDetail>>(sJSON);

    //iterate your list here
}

public class StoreDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("dateNumeric")]
    public string DateNumeric { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hourOfDay")]
    public int HourOfDay { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("customerNumber")]
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("storedepartment")]
    public List<StoreDepartment> StoreDepartment { get; set; }

}

public class StoreDepartment
{
    [JsonProperty("department")]
    public int Department { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("descriptionOfDepartment")]
    public string DescriptionOfDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string sJSON = @"   [{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":0,""customerNumber"":12,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":333,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department A""},{""department"":111,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department B""}]},{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":3,""customerNumber"":3,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":999,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department X""},{""department"":888,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department Y""}]}]";

object dJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(sJSON);
Console.WriteLine(dJson.ToString());

JArray a = JArray.Parse(sJSON);

foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
    {
        if (p.First.Count() == 0)
        {
            string name = p.Name;
            string value = (string)p.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(name + "-- " + value);
        }
        else
        {
            string name = p.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            string subStr = p.Value.ToString();
            JArray aSub = JArray.Parse(subStr);
            foreach (JObject oSub in aSub.Children<JObject>())
            {
                foreach (JProperty pSub in oSub.Properties())
                {
                    string nameSub = pSub.Name;
                    string valueSub = (string)pSub.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + nameSub + "-- " + valueSub);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```